# Prestashop BlockLayered Navigation doesn't filter

Tags: caching, navigation, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, blocklayered

I have problem with with BlockLayered Navigation doesn't filter. I see at categories/subcategories, but when I check some filter nothing happens...
It is Prestashop 1.6.11 I've tried with cache on and off but it doesn't help.

Anyone had the same problem?

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

Do you have in module Blocklayred, regenerate urls, filters and prices?

Regards,